# jQuery requests on mobile application not working

Tags: javascript, php, android, jquery, ajax

I am making a mobile application using Intel XDK for Android devices, I have been using an emulator and my local development server (127.0.0.1) to test my PHP code. I have been contacting my server using the following ways `$.ajax()`, `$.post()` and `$.get()`. I then decided that I'd reached a suitable point where I should build the application APK file, push the PHP source on to a online website and test it through a proper mobile. So I did, I made the database by exporting my current data from PMA then changed all the URLs in all my requests to point to the right place and pushed my PHP source to the FTP. I then tested my application and was quite shocked by the results.

**Error #1**:

> PHP Fatal error:  Can't use function return value in write context in
>   /home/scrifalr/public_html/sm/api/v1/modules/register/register.php on
>   line 9

**What I did to fix**:

I checked the source and apparently after changing this `!empty(trim($_POST['username']))` to `empty($_POST['username'])` seemed to fix that error.

So ***question one***. Why did this error not show up on my local server and not tell me then that I can't do that?

**Error #2**:

I have a login/register which sends requests which all works, I changed the above PHP and they started to work. However I have a logout page which doesn't seem to work, the code is shown below:

logout.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
    <script src="intelxdk.js"></script>
    <script src="cordova.js"></script>
    <script src="xhr.js"></script>
    <script src="js/libs/app.js"></script>
    <script src="js/libs/functions.js"></script>
    <script src="js/logout.js"></script>
    <title>Logout</title>
</head>

<body>

</body>

</html>
```

As you can see, it has nothing besides the includes. The following file is the JavaScript file:

logout.js

```
window.onload = function () {
    getSessionData();
    $.post(
        "http://sm.script47.net/api/v1/modules/logout/logout.php", {
            "userID": window.userID
        }, function (data) {
            alert(data);
            if (data == 1) {
                document.location.href = "index.html";
            } else {
                showTimedMessage(data, "error", 4000);
            }
        }
    );
};
```

As you can see, it contains the post request and a function called `getSessionData()`, so after what seemed like an age of trying to debug I came to the conclusion that it is `getSessionData()` which is failing which again seems odd as it was working in the emulator and all the paths to the requested files are correct. Just for those who would like to see that function:

```
window.token = null;
window.userID = null;
window.username = null;
window.emailAddress = null;
window.IP = null;

function getSessionData() {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://sm.script47.net/api/v1/modules/sessionData/sessionData.php',
        "type": "GET",
        dataType: "json",
        async: false // This comment is not in the code, I know I shouldn't have this I'm using it for now and it works with it like this.
    }).done(function (data) {
        window.token = data.token;
        window.userID = data.userID;
        window.username = data.username;
        window.emailAddress = data.emailAddress;
    }); 
}
```

So ***question two*** is that how come even after I tested it thoroughly and ensured that all the paths are correct and uploaded the exact same code, why are some requests being sent e.g. login, register yet others (logout) not working?

Comment: because you don't understand basic concepts of each program language. if you want to get better these are the words you need to hear. I would have never learned much code at all if i hadn't of been banned from stackoverflow.

Comment: edited to explain why such a "rude" answer was posted. i'll give you a hint. you need to specifically look at the jquery `$.ajax` api. you can set a callback function for errors and determine what the error is, if its coming from php. if not from php, you can look in the console if its coming from javascript.

Comment: @r3wt agreed, I am not as experienced in front end coding as I am back end, but I have tried? I only turned to StackOverFlow after I knew I had extinguished all other possibilities. The code was working fine, which surely means I had some understanding of concepts. Yet it broke in the transition from emulator to mobile. Which is why I turned to StackOverFlow to help me understand why it broke and this will help me for future references too. So no I don't agree with your statement, maybe I'll learn more if people teach me where I went wrong, no?

Comment: does your server allow CORS?

Comment: @r3wt Sorry, but how can I check that?

Comment: if you are making a cross origin request(for example from a mobile phone) over http, your server needs to be configured to allow CORS. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS

Comment: Yes, as far as I am aware, It's working. As I am already sending requests to the new server through the emulator. So it must allow it to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some more debugging it turned out the AJAX call was failing because synchronous AJAX calls are not allowed.